# three.js add name and id to loading model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am loading more than object into the scene, so i want to differentiate each models loaded by their **name** and **id**, so while load the models am adding the **name** and **id** as like below in my code

```
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(object_material));
model = new THREE.Object3D();
model.id="Myid"+file;
model.name="Myname"+file;
model.add(object);    
model.position.set(x,y,z);             
model.scale.set(obj_width,obj_height,obj_rotation);    
model.opacity   =2;
model.rotation.y = 600;
model.duration = 12000;
model.mirroredLoop = true;
model.castShadow = true;
model.receiveShadow = true;
console.log(model);   
scene.add(model);
```

on the console i can see the model **name** and **id** as like below

```
Object { id="Myid746834", uuid="8AD0FF6C-83C9-4219-8CBB-C3B0E931416D", name="Myname746834", more...}
3d_tool...proid=3 (line 814)
Object { id="Myid746834", uuid="3FA3A69A-A5C9-40DD-A564-37F622C68872", name="Myname746834", more...}
Object { id="Myid746834", uuid="F46501A5-EDB6-453D-9871-568FE9EC8E6D", name="Myname746834", more...}
3d_tool...proid=3 (line 814)
Object { id="Myid816595", uuid="BEA53331-A331-46F6-9D8C-3BDC9A77312B", name="Myname816595", more...}
3d_tool...proid=3 (line 814)
Object { id="Myid215834", uuid="B84C740A-0D95-4C84-AA1E-578C2D6CDB1C", name="Myname215834", more...}
```

so here the **name** and id is set into the **objects** i loaded, but after i want to get the this in `onMouseDown` to find the selected model and it's name,id, but there am not getting the assigned name,id of previously set into the objects instead of it am getting

```
objects id :21
objects name:
```

like this, meaning that id is differ from assigned and name it empty, any guess on this ?

Comment: Please also post the contents of your onMouseDown event, or show how you are trying to access the element by ID

Comment: hi @Shiva you can get my onMouseDown function on here http://pastebin.com/RzyHibca

Comment: Do not overwrite Object3D.id. Set Object3D.userData.id instead.

Comment: share your code in jsfiddle.. so that we can give correct suggestion.. here you have assign name and id to object3d, intersect will return object(i.e, its a mesh). so look for intersects[0].object.parent.id and intersects[0].object.parent.name

Comment: Hi @user2089677 you get my code here http://pastebin.com/RzyHibca